# Pass Value from one LWC to Another LWC on button click in Parent LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

**Parent**

Template

```
<lightning-button variant="brand" label="Next" onclick={FixtureType1Page}> 
</lightning-button>
<div if:true={FixtureType1flag}>
   <c-data-collection></c-data-collection>
</div>
```

JS
I dont know what to write in Parent JS

**Child**

Tempalate

```
 <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <p>Technolgy Bulb Type</p>
                <template for:each={TechData} for:item="item">
                    <lightning-radio-group style="padding:6px 12px;margin:0 0 15px 
                      0;display:inline-block;"
                        value={item.value}
                        key={item.value}
                        label={item.label}
                        data-value={item.value}
                        onclick={TechDataFn}
                        variant="neutral" >
                    </lightning-radio-group >
                </template>
            </div>
```

js

```
FixtureType1Page() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            getTechnolgies({})
            .then(Techcnologies => {
                this.Location=Techcnologies;
                const TechTempArry = [];
                Techcnologies.forEach(function (element) {
                    let myArray = {};
                    myArray.value = element.Name
                    myArray.label = element.Technology_Bulb_Type__c
                    TechTempArry.push(myArray);
                });
                this.TechData = TechTempArry;
                console.log('TechData'+TechData);
                this.error = undefined;
                return resolve(true);

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("error..ewew."+error);
                return reject(error);

            });
        //const selectedVal = this.TechBulbType;
        this.FixtureType1flag = true;
        this.Keyflag = false;

        this.selectService.classList.remove('currentFrom');
        this.selectService.classList.add('finish');
        this.dataCollection.classList.add("currentFrom");
    });
    }
```

So if click on button in my parent LWC then function in child lwc should call and fetch the list

Answer (score 1):

You can send a prop value from parent component to c data collection.

```
<c-data-collection childvalue={parentvalue} ></c-data-collection>
```

define **@track parentvalue** inside parent.js and pass this value to child.

Now inside child.js, you have to define **@api childvalue**

When you click FixtureType1Page button you can update the **parentvalue** variable inside this function since **parentvalue** is tracked variable it will rerender the page and will update the **childvalue** inside the data collection component since child value is **@api declaration**

You can find more about @track and @api here

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.reactivity_public

Answer (score 0):

To make the function: FixtureType1Page() visible for parent you need to add @api decorator at begining of definition:
@api FixtureType1Page() { ...